# How to determine Asp.Net Session Length

Tags: asp.net, session-state

The SessionState time out value can be configured via the web.config

```
<sessionstate 
      timeout="x"/>
```

My question is: how can I determine through code, what the SessionState timeout length is?

Comment: Duh....
you can get it via Session.Timeout

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get or set that value using [HttpSessionState.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)